# Android:Grid View

Tags: android, gridview, view

I want to ask how can i resize the size of the grid to a larger size according to my needs.

here is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:gravity="center" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my layout file:

```
package com.example.steve_jobs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


        }
    });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;


 }

}
```

image adapter class:

```
package com.example.steve_jobs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

/**
 * Created by yash on 19/6/13.
 */
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sj_1,
        R.drawable.sj_2,
        R.drawable.sj_3,
        R.drawable.sj_4,
        R.drawable.sj_5,
        R.drawable.sj_6,
        R.drawable.sj_7,
         R.drawable.nexus
 };


}
```

Comment: what you want to re size, if you want to columnwidth re size the increase/decrease the column width in dp

Answer (score 0):

You could remove or reduce all that padding!

edit:

try

```
android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
```

0, 1 and 2 represent indexes of your columns;

so if you have 6 columns you would use "0,1,2,3,4,5"

Comment: actually when i open the application then only two grid appears in every row and too of very small size. I mean i want then to cover the whole screen but they appear to be very small and remaining space is all white.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/myGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"    
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```